# Is it possible to increase the number of centroids in KMeans during fitting?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am attempting to use MiniBatchKMeans to stream NLP data in and cluster it, but have no way of determining how many clusters I need. What I would like to do is periodically take the silhouette score and if it drops below a certain threshold, increase the number of centroids. But as far as I can tell, `n_clusters` is set when you initialize the clusterer and can't be changed without restarting. Am I wrong here? Is there another way to approach this problem that would avoid this issue?

Comment: Despite the fact, that k-means is heuristic, i'm pretty sure that the change of the number of clusters during running would have extremely negative effects on the alternating-minimization-kind of algorithm used (you will stuck in a local minimum and got only there because of now-obsolete parameters). This is at least, what i think! Just optimize for different values of ```n_cluster```and compare your scores (if you trust them). k-means should be fast enough to do this kind of validation-strategy. This approach will be much more stable!

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to do this during optimization, because it changes the optimization procedure substantially. It will essentially reset the whole optimization. There are strategies such as bisecting k-means that try to learn the value of k during clustering, but they are a bit more tricky than increasing k by one - they decide upon one particular cluster to split, and try to choose good initial centroids for this cluster to keep things somewhat stable.

Furthermore, increasing k will not necessarily improve Silhouette. It will trivially improve SSQ, so you cannot use SSQ as a heuristic for choosing k, either.

Last but not least, computing the Silhouette is O(n^2). It is too expensive to run often. If you have large enough amount of data to require MiniBatchKMeans (which *really* is only for massive data), then you clearly cannot afford to compute Silhouette at all.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't know that, and it's >50gb of metadata, so yes, it's big

Comment: Then let me give you one important advice: **use a sample first**, to test your approach. Only scale approaches that *work* to your full data. Because in my experience, k-means will disappoint you (Please let me know whether it gave you good results!) - I've always been considering to do some work on k-means (and I have some nice ideas), but it never worked well on my problems.